# git does not ignore a file

Tags: git, github

I accidentally tracked the `.idea/workspace.xml` file created by rubymine and now i can't seem to remove the file from being tracked.

It's been checked in multiple times because of this, but i'd really like it to stop being tracked because is causes merge conflicts.

Here's how i keep trying to remove the file.

1. `git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml`

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch master
   Changes to be committed:
   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

   deleted:    .idea/workspace.xml
   ```
2. `git commit -m 'remove workspace file from tracking'`
3. add this entry to my .gitignore file `.idea/*`

Comment: Have you tried deleting (`git rm .idea/workspace.xml`) first, then committing and adding it to .gitignore afterward?

Comment: Hillary, that would have to do the trick. What do you get after running those 3 steps you do? Are you sure you're really committing the deletion?

Comment: Is the .gitignore file being committed too?

Comment: i'd been committing the .gitignore. on my local machine so far it seems that removing the parent folder completely, instead of just hte cached version seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown should work fine. I see two potential ways the file may be repeatedly reintroduced:

- If somebody else is still getting merge errors and resolving them by adding their changes and ignoring your deletion, file will keep coming back
- If you're not including your `.gitignore` in your repo or not committing your addition of `.ideas/*` to the .gitignore, other people are likely re-adding the file via something like

  ```
  git add -a
  ```

  or

  ```
  git add .
  ```

  You should commit your changes to your .gitignore to keep this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by using the GitHub Windows GUI tool.

Even though I manually removed the .idea/ folder in .gitignore and executed `git rm -r --cached .idea`, it would keep coming back in "Unsynced Changes".

I was able to solve this by **manually committing via command-line** after removing the cached folder and adding to .gitignore. Not sure why but it works.

`git commit -m "Manual commit"`

Answer (score 0):

Once a file is commited there are 2 ways to tell git to ignore it:

1. Commit the removal of the file and then add it to `.gitignore`

   git rm --cached 
    git commit -m "Removed ..."
2. Set the `assume-unchanged` flag

### ***`--[no-]assume-unchanged`***

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.